# Problema em linha vazia - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou com um problema, tenho alguns meses de experiencia em `Laravel` e não vi este tipo de problema acontecer, ao submeter um formulário aparece o seguinte erro:

> `Error Exception
>    Trying to get property of non-object in LivroController.php (line 206)`

Um erro assim já vi várias vezes, porém ao ir até o arquivo e linha especificadas percebo que na linha não existe nada.

**`LivroController.php`**

```
if($aluno->StatusAluno == 1)
{
        //Se o aluno já tenha um livro, ele retorna a mensagem
       Session::flash('mensagemError','O aluno já tem um livro emprestado');
       return redirect()
                 ->action('MainController@index');
}
else
{
     //esta é a linha 206, este comentário não existe no código

     //------------Fim da verificação do Aluno-------------- 

     //------------Verificação do Livro --------------

     if($l->is_disp == 0) { ...
```

já dei `php artisan config:clear` no `cmd` e não mudou nada.

Comment: é melhor colocar o `Controller` completo e também o erro! assim está muito vago.!

Comment: o problema é que este é um método muito grande(cerca de 170 linhas)

Comment: é um erro local, é complicado avaliar e dizer o seu problema!

Comment: você pode usar o isset antes de verificar o status do aluno, `isset($aluno->StatusAluno) && $aluno->StatusAluno  == 1`